# Can I use M[*it]++ for insertion in Map data structure ?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have declared a **Vecto**r which contains a set of pairs of int values:-

```
vector<set<pair<int,int>>> V;
```

Now, suppose I want to insert the vector elements as **key values** in a **Map**. Can I use the following code for doing so:

```
map<pair<int,int>,int> M;

for(int i=0;i<V.size();i++){

        if(!included[i])
        for(auto it = V[i].begin();it!=V[i].end();it++)
        {
            M[*it]++;
        }
    }
```

If , the answer is yes then:

1) What will be the **mapped values** for each cases?

2) While iterating trough the vector; `it` should find only Sets so `*it` should return Set, not pair. But how it retrieves pair of int values?

3) How the insertion process actually going on using **[] operator** ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: Great!  Many thanks @juanchopanza . It helps to the point

Comment: Can you please rephrase your second question? `it` is of type `set<pair<int,int>>::iterator` and `*it` is of type `pair<int,int>`, which shall be correct. The code compiles fine.

Comment: **(1)**  A count of how many times each specific pair was encountered during the iteration. **(2)** The inner loop is iterating over `V[i]` which is a `set<pair<int, int>>`, not a vector; this question starts with a false premise. **(3)** The insertion is going on in a manner documented for `map::operator[]`; I suppose I don't understand this question.

Comment: Yes.. later I read some documentations about that and I realize a lot of insights about this. Thanks @IgorTandetnik for Your answer.